# i installed python 3.9, all my libraries installed using pip doesnt work in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, anaconda

i installed python 3.9 and then installed anaconda for use jupyter notebook.
why all the packages than i install using pip install selenium (for ex) doesnt work in jupyter notebook?

all the packages installed using pip install must work but didnt

HELP ME PLEASE

Thnks you

Answer (score 0):

This must be due to jupyter notebook and python (in the terminal) using two different installations of python. Jupyter notebook generally uses anaconda, which is not the default in the terminal. Then, any libraries installed won't reflect in anaconda.

You can either move the anaconda installation to `PATH`, or can run `!pip install [library]` in the jupyter notebook.